# Check if square intersects line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, geometry, line-intersection

Given the position and dimensions of a square, what is the equation in JavaScript for testing if a line goes through the rectangle?

What I have tried so far is:

```
function isSquareIntersectingLine(square, line) {
    return (
        line.startX >= square.topLeftX &&
        line.startX <= square.topLeftX + square.width &&
        line.endX >= square.topLeftX + square.width
    );
}
```

This works for if the dimensions are:

```
Square: {topLeftX: 0, topLeftY: 0, width: 5, height: 5}
Line: {startX: 2, startY: -4, endX: 6, endY: 3}
```

But if the dimensions are like this, it won't work:

```
Square: {topLeftX: 0, topLeftY: 0, width: 5, height: 5}
Line: {startX: 2, startY: -4, endX: 3, endY: 10}
```

**What is the correct formula for checking if a line segment intersects a square in JavaScript?**

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1968345/8526705

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Cohen-Sutherland clipping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm) (or another [line clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_clipping) one)

Get codes for both segments ends and check:

```
if both codes are zero, segment is inside (A-B case)
if code1 & code2 != 0 segment is outside  (K-L case)
if code1 & code2 = 0, analyze codes
    zero-nonzero: intersection exists (C-D)
    if code1 | code2 = 1100, 0011 : intersection exists (E-F)
         otherwise check for intersections with edges (GH)
```

[image]